# JSONDecodeError in Google Translate API

Tags: python, json, google-translation-api

I am trying to translate some data using [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) python library. The below program first worked fine and after processing some requests it gives a `JSONDecodeError`. After some searching I found that Google may be blocking my IP address after a limited number of requests. Is this the actual problem? If then is there a solution? (Ex: using a vpn). Or else is there a fault in my code that causes the error?

> My Code

```
import glob
import errno
import json
from googletrans import Translator
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.knowledge
en_entities = db.en_entities
ta_entities = db.ta_entities

translator = Translator()

path = '../data/DialogFlow Data/entities/*entries*.json'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            entities = json.load(f)
            for entity in entities:
                synonyms = []
                translations = translator.translate(entity['synonyms'], dest='ta')
                for translation in translations:
                    synonyms.append(translation.text)
                dic = {'value': entity['value'], 'synonyms': synonyms}
                ta_entities.insert_one(dic)
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

> Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/125/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/125/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/125/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/125/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/kabilesh/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/entity_handlers/put_entities.py", line 38, in <module>
    translations = translator.translate(entity['synonyms'], dest='ta')
  File "/home/kabilesh/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 167, in translate
    translated = self.translate(item, dest=dest, src=src)
  File "/home/kabilesh/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 172, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "/home/kabilesh/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 81, in _translate
    data = utils.format_json(r.text)
  File "/home/kabilesh/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py", line 62, in format_json
    converted = legacy_format_json(original)
  File "/home/kabilesh/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py", line 54, in legacy_format_json
    converted = json.loads(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

> One of the JSON files

```
[
  {
    "value": "Xiaomi",
    "synonyms": [
      "Xiaomi",
      "xiao mi",
      "MI",
      "mi"
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "Android",
    "synonyms": [
      "Android",
      "android",
      "google os",
      "andriod"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Start a debugger, put a breakpoint on the failed line and inspect actual response

Comment: catch the actual error. it probably means you are not getting back a JSON object, maybe 404 error. response should carry the error text

Comment: Even simple code in this https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/ documentation gives the same error. It is google blocking me :(

Comment: That can be a reason. Since the author of googletrans states this under "How does this library work": "I eventually figure out a way to generate a ticket by reverse engineering on the obfuscated and minified code used by Google to generate such token, and implemented on the top of Python. However, this could be blocked at any time." But you can still check the error. I wouldn't rely on such library though..

Comment: Isn't there any free and unlimited library or API for translation?