# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) ---Python

Tags: python

I tried to follow the [tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/text-translation-with-google-translate-api-in-python/#:~:text=Translating%20Text%20Documents,to%20the%20translate()%20method.&text=You%20can%20also%20check%20whether,if%20f.) of using google translator in python, when I come to the code where `result = translator.translate('Mitä sinä teet')`, I got such error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-7ae6cd50c95e> in <module>
      1 from googletrans import Translator
      2 translator = Translator()
----> 3 result = translator.translate('Mitä sinä teet')
      4 print(result.src)
      5 print(result.dest)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
     79         r = self.session.get(url, params=params)
     80 
---> 81         data = utils.format_json(r.text)
     82         return data
     83 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py in format_json(original)
     60         converted = json.loads(original)
     61     except ValueError:
---> 62         converted = legacy_format_json(original)
     63 
     64     return converted

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py in legacy_format_json(original)
     52             text = text[:p] + states[j][1] + text[nxt:]
     53 
---> 54     converted = json.loads(text)
     55     return converted
     56 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have no idea why this simple code won't work on my computer. I'm using mac and Python 3. Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: strange. seems like you're getting bad data from google, or something like that. Could you please try to run it again and see if the problem persists?

Comment: I had tried to uninstall and reinstall the googletrans package, still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you think you can run this with a debugger, and put a breakpoint in ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py / line 54? (converted = json.loads(text)). that way, you can know what's the bad JSON, and hopefully figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Also - have a look at this one. Seems like Google may be blocking you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533634/jsondecodeerror-in-google-translate-api.

Comment: yes I think probably google is blocking me, do you have any suggestion on translation tool in python?