# Python googletrans not work properly after long iteration

Tags: python, json, google-translate

I just tried to convert my JSON object fields data to my mother tongue (Sinhala). But sometimes it's not converted correctly.
For example when I convert,

```
{ "artist_name": "Ajith Mutukumarana"}
```

sometimes it converted correctly as

```
{"artist_name":"අජිත් මුතුකුමාරණ"}
```

sometime its not converted correctly,

```
{ "artist_name": "Ajith Mutukumarana"}
```

It seems to be, with time and after long iteration, this issue is coming.
My code is,

```
translator=Translator()

def convert_to_sinhala(text):     
  if(text==None):
        return None
  else:
        tra=translator.translate(text,dest="si").text 
        return tra


def format_song(song):
  obj = {
    "artist_name" :  convert_to_sinhala(song['artist_name'])
  }
  return obj
#my json object list with 1000 objects
for song in objects:
    
    obj = format_song(song) 
    print(obj)
```

Please suggest how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Verify that you didn't reach the API limit. There are multiple questions in SO about this - for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533634/jsondecodeerror-in-google-translate-api

Comment: yeah, because sometime last JSON object converted correctly. But the middle some of the objects have this issue.